# WebStorm Live Template for JSX, include default field without definition

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, live-templates

I'm trying to create a live template for a `Route` component in WebStorm:

```
<Route exact path="$PATH$" component={$COMPONENT$}/>$END$
```

The problem is that it completes like so:

[image]

I don't want to give any 'definition' to `exact`. I just want it to look like:

```
<Route exact path=$VAR1$ component={$VAR2$} />
```

I've tried escaping it in a couple of different ways, and I can't currently find any information about this [from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/creating-and-editing-template-variables.html).

How do I create a live template for something like this?

Edit: here's an image of my config:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you have another (bundled) Live Template already for that? IDE should not be altering your code (adding something else) when you expand Live Template abbreviation. 1) Show how that Live Template is defined 2) Show exactly what you see just before you hit an expand key (`Tab` I guess) that expands abbreviation into an actual code snippet. You should be seeing code completion popup at that point.

Comment: I've tried disabling all my templates except this one, and the behaviour is the same. I've shown how the live template is defined above. There's nothing that is shown before I hit tab. I just type Route and then hit tab. I'll add another picture though to be clear.

Comment: Try uncheck "Reformat according to style".  You do have `exact` present in actual Live Template but in different form (no `=""` part). Reformatting might be doing just that. Otherwise I have no idea where else that extra stuff might be coming from...

Comment: Didn't help. I reported it as a bug to Jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30199